# How do I get around this install error for CosmWasm on my 64-bit Windows Laptop?

Tags: c++, go, build

I am trying to install the CosmWasm smart contracting platform on a Windows Laptop based on their tutorial at https://docs.cosmwasm.com/docs/1.0/getting-started/installation but when I try to run the make install command I get this error. Does anyone know what the problem could be? I'm using the gcc.exe from TDM-GCC because it works better for my 64-bit system than mingw-w64 did.

```
$ make install
which: no docker in (/c/Users/lstil/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/lstil/bin:/:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Python39/Scripts:/c/Program Files/Go/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/NetSarang/Xlpd 6:/c/Program Files (x86)/NetSarang/Xshell 6:/c/Program Files (x86)/NetSarang/Xmanager 6:/c/windows/system32:/c/windows:/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Users/lstil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38:/c/Users/lstil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts:/c/Program Files (x86)/Wiimm/WIT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Wiimm/SZS:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/PuTTY:/cmd:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/TDM-GCC-64/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin:/c/Users/lstil/.cargo/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/NetSarang/Xlpd 6:/c/Program Files (x86)/NetSarang/Xshell 6:/c/Program Files (x86)/NetSarang/Xmanager 6:/c/windows/system32:/c/windows:/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NGX:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/cmd:/c/Users/lstil/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Python27/Scripts:/c/Program Files (x86)/Wiimm/WIT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Wiimm/SZS:/c/Users/lstil/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin:/c/Program Files/emacs/bin:/c/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin:/c/Users/lstil/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/lstil/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/lstil/go/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
go install -mod=readonly -tags "netgo,ledger" -ldflags '-X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.Name=wasm -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.AppName=wasmd -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.Version=0.21.0 -X github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.Commit=4ffba672739a41d395827b78cb610f4a51eea83c -X github.com/CosmWasm/wasmd/app.Bech32Prefix=wasm -X "github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/version.BuildTags=netgo,ledger"' -trimpath ./cmd/wasmd
# github.com/CosmWasm/wasmvm/api
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_analyze_code':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:56: undefined reference to `analyze_code'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_execute':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:90: undefined reference to `execute'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_get_metrics':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:113: undefined reference to `get_metrics'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_ibc_channel_close':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:146: undefined reference to `ibc_channel_close'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_ibc_channel_connect':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:179: undefined reference to `ibc_channel_connect'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_ibc_channel_open':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:212: undefined reference to `ibc_channel_open'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_ibc_packet_ack':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:245: undefined reference to `ibc_packet_ack'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_ibc_packet_receive':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:278: undefined reference to `ibc_packet_receive'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_ibc_packet_timeout':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:311: undefined reference to `ibc_packet_timeout'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_init_cache':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:337: undefined reference to `init_cache'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_instantiate':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:371: undefined reference to `instantiate'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_load_wasm':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:395: undefined reference to `load_wasm'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_migrate':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:428: undefined reference to `migrate'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_pin':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:449: undefined reference to `pin'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_query':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:479: undefined reference to `query'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_reply':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:512: undefined reference to `reply'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_save_wasm':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:536: undefined reference to `save_wasm'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_sudo':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:569: undefined reference to `sudo'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_C2func_unpin':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:590: undefined reference to `unpin'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_analyze_code':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:609: undefined reference to `analyze_code'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_execute':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:639: undefined reference to `execute'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_get_metrics':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:658: undefined reference to `get_metrics'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_ibc_channel_close':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:687: undefined reference to `ibc_channel_close'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_ibc_channel_connect':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:716: undefined reference to `ibc_channel_connect'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_ibc_channel_open':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:745: undefined reference to `ibc_channel_open'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_ibc_packet_ack':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:774: undefined reference to `ibc_packet_ack'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_ibc_packet_receive':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:803: undefined reference to `ibc_packet_receive'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_ibc_packet_timeout':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:832: undefined reference to `ibc_packet_timeout'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_init_cache':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:854: undefined reference to `init_cache'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_instantiate':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:884: undefined reference to `instantiate'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_load_wasm':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:904: undefined reference to `load_wasm'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_migrate':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:933: undefined reference to `migrate'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_pin':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:950: undefined reference to `pin'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_query':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:976: undefined reference to `query'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_reply':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:1017: undefined reference to `reply'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_save_wasm':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:1037: undefined reference to `save_wasm'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_sudo':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:1066: undefined reference to `sudo'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_unpin':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:1083: undefined reference to `unpin'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x004.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_release_cache':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:991: undefined reference to `release_cache'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x005.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_destroy_unmanaged_vector':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:49: undefined reference to `destroy_unmanaged_vector'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b064\_x005.o: in function `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_new_unmanaged_vector':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:67: undefined reference to `new_unmanaged_vector'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:93: install] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages come from the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) (hence `ld.exe`) of GCC: for a number of object files (those with the `.o` extension) which were built by `go install` it tries to find *something* (see below) which contains a set of function the code in those object files wants to call in order to function properly.

The names of the functions look like `_cgo_d3f6466c8ed4_Cfunc_new_unmanaged_vector`, where that "_cgo" prefix clearly means the Go code which was built wanted to call out to a library exporting a C-compatible interface (API) via the usage of [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

Now, after exploiting my mad Internet search skillz, I've managed to find, say [this](https://github.com/CosmWasm/wasmvm/search?q=destroy_unmanaged_vector&type=code) which, to me, means two things:

- Whatever code you're trying to build (`wasmd`) imports `github.com/CosmWasm/wasmvm`.
- The latter *supposedly* wants to link against a C-compatible library which, I fathom, is written in Rust.

I have no idea where to move from there, really: this library might have been created but is not in the path GCC uses to find the libs.
This can be fixed by passing an appropriate `-L` command-line option to the C compiler but I have no idea how to do that in this case.

So I'd ask the devs, actually.

*Update:* [this file](https://github.com/CosmWasm/wasmvm/blob/16e8e0a7648823ab0c060aadf60f75236af168e5/api/link_std.go) actually has cgo-related stuff for GCC, but it is explicitly build-tagged as non-`windows`; looks like the devs simply did not know how it should be built on Windows.
I'd try to add `windows` to the build tag of that file and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was using WSL2 to run linux within Windows 10. Use this link for how to install and setup WSL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment

From within your linux window, you can install everything following the cosmwasm documentation. In my case I was following docs.terra.money and got the local test net running using WSL2.